# c# ValueInjecter : Mapping the whole object Graph

Tags: c#, dto, valueinjecter, object-object-mapping

I just started using ValueInjecter for my Entity Mappings(DTO <-> Entity).
Heres my DTO :

```
public class IncidentDTO
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    AgencyDTO agencyDTO { get; set; }
}

public class AgencyDTO
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<IncidentTypeDTO> incidentTypeDTOList { get; set; }
}

public class IncidentTypeDTO
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string TypeName { get; set; }
}
```

Heres my NHibernate Proxy classes :

```
 public class Incident
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    Agency agency { get; set; }
}

public class Agency
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class IncidentType
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string TypeName { get; set; }
}

public class AgencyIncidentType
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    Agency agency { get; set; }
    IncidentType incidentType { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I need to query `IncidentDTO` from Repository. 
Repository query `Incident` & `AgencyIncidentType` tables from database and map `Incident` -> `IncidentDTO` using ValueInjecter and return `IncidentDTO`.

What is the best possible way to do the above mapping using ValueInjecter??

Thanks,
Prateek

Comment: look at http://prodinner.codeplex.com, it uses valueinjecter for the exact same thing that you are doing, it also has a pdf explaining that

Comment: Thanks Chuck!! thats exactly what i was looking for, `ConventionInjection` for `IEnumerable` types.... Also @Gloppy's answer pointed me to Deep Cloning + `ConventionInjection for IEnumerable` so i am marking it as answer.. Thanks guys for help!! and Chuck for making object-object mapping so much easier..;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to map `Incident` to `IncidentDTO` while retaining and mapping the `Agency` object in the `agency` property (to an `AgencyDTO`) of an `Incident` instance I'd suggest renaming the `agencyDTO` property to `agency` in your `IncidentDTO` and then use a tweak to the CloneInjection sample from the Value Injector documentation as described here: [omu.valueinjecter deep clone unlike types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249891/omu-valueinjecter-deep-clone-unlike-types/10842907#10842907)

Comment: Thanks Gloppy!! everything i wanted in one place..;)