# Steps to map classes using ValueInjector

Tags: collections, mapping, valueinjecter

Quickly getting to the problem the mapping does not occur for the following code. Could someone explain why? or what i should do for the mapping to occur?

```cs
var parent = new Parent();
parent.ChildOne.Add(new ChildOne() { Name = "Child One" });
parent.ChildTwo.Add(new ChildTwo() { Name = "Child Two" });
AnotherParent anotherParent = new AnotherParent();

anotherParent.InjectFrom<LoopValueInjection>(parent);
```

Required Class are below

#### Anothher child one

```cs
 public class AnotherChildOne
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

#### Another child two

```cs
 public class AnotherChildTwo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

#### Another Parent

```cs
public class AnotherParent
    {
        public ICollection<AnotherChildOne> ChildOne { get; set; }

        public ICollection<AnotherChildTwo> ChildTwo { get; set; }

        public AnotherParent()
        {
            ChildOne = new Collection<AnotherChildOne>();
            ChildTwo = new Collection<AnotherChildTwo>();
        }


    }
```

#### Child Two

```cs
public class ChildTwo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

#### Child One

```cs
 public class ChildOne
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

#### Parent

```cs
 public class Parent
    {

        public ICollection<ChildOne> ChildOne { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ChildTwo> ChildTwo { get; set; }

        public Parent()
        {
            ChildOne = new Collection<ChildOne>();
            ChildTwo = new Collection<ChildTwo>();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe by default Value Injector will only inject the properties with the same name of the same type. You can get around this using a tweak to the `CloneInjection` sample from the Value Injector documentation as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10842907/1207991) with this code:

```cs
public class CloneInjection : ConventionInjection
{
    protected override bool Match(ConventionInfo c)
    {
        return c.SourceProp.Name == c.TargetProp.Name && c.SourceProp.Value != null;
    }

    protected override object SetValue(ConventionInfo c)
    {
        //for value types and string just return the value as is
        if (c.SourceProp.Type.IsValueType || c.SourceProp.Type == typeof(string)
            || c.TargetProp.Type.IsValueType || c.TargetProp.Type == typeof(string))
            return c.SourceProp.Value;

        //handle arrays
        if (c.SourceProp.Type.IsArray)
        {
            var arr = c.SourceProp.Value as Array;
            var clone = Activator.CreateInstance(c.TargetProp.Type, arr.Length) as Array;

            for (int index = 0; index < arr.Length; index++)
            {
                var a = arr.GetValue(index);
                if (a.GetType().IsValueType || a.GetType() == typeof(string)) continue;
                clone.SetValue(Activator.CreateInstance(c.TargetProp.Type.GetElementType()).InjectFrom<CloneInjection>(a), index);
            }
            return clone;
        }


        if (c.SourceProp.Type.IsGenericType)
        {
            //handle IEnumerable<> also ICollection<> IList<> List<>
            if (c.SourceProp.Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IEnumerable)))
            {
                var t = c.TargetProp.Type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                if (t.IsValueType || t == typeof(string)) return c.SourceProp.Value;

                var tlist = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(t);
                var list = Activator.CreateInstance(tlist);

                var addMethod = tlist.GetMethod("Add");
                foreach (var o in c.SourceProp.Value as IEnumerable)
                {
                    var e = Activator.CreateInstance(t).InjectFrom<CloneInjection>(o);
                    addMethod.Invoke(list, new[] { e }); // in 4.0 you can use dynamic and just do list.Add(e);
                }
                return list;
            }

            //unhandled generic type, you could also return null or throw
            return c.SourceProp.Value;
        }

        //for simple object types create a new instace and apply the clone injection on it
        return Activator.CreateInstance(c.TargetProp.Type)
            .InjectFrom<CloneInjection>(c.SourceProp.Value);
    }
}
```

If you include the above `CloneInjection` code you will want to do this:

```cs
anotherParent.InjectFrom<CloneInjection>(parent);
```

instead of:

```cs
anotherParent.InjectFrom<LoopValueInjection>(parent);
```